# Why is this code returning NaN for mark.BMI

Tags: javascript, function, object

```js
var mark = {
    firstName: 'Mark',
    height: 6.2,
    mass: 180,
    calcBMI: function(height, mass) {
        this.BMI = mass / (height^2);
    }
};

mark.calcBMI();
console.log(mark);
```

Working on some newbie stuff. This feels like it should work, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: `mass` and `height` are not standalone variables, they are properties of the instance

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't support anything like an implicit `this`; therefore in `calcBMI`, `mass` and `height` are undefined. Also, you're defining a `mass` and `height` parameter, but when you're calling `mark.calcBMI`, you're not *passing arguments* for those parameters.

It should also be noted that `^` is the XOR operator. The exponentiation operator is `**`.

Try this instead:

```
var mark = {
    firstName: 'Mark',
    height: 6.2,
    mass: 180,
    calcBMI: function() {
        this.BMI = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
    }
};

mark.calcBMI();
console.log(mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mark = {
    firstName: 'Mark',
    height: 6.2,
    mass: 180,
    calcBMI: function() {
        this.BMI = this.mass / (Math.pow(this.height,2));
    }
};

mark.calcBMI();
console.log(mark);
```

Just need to add `this` to the beginning and use `Math.pow()` instead of the `^` since that is the XOR operator, not the exponentiation operator.

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense.  Thank you!